# Vehicle doesn't react to drive commands in current default branch of gazebo/drcsim built from source

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi everyone, the [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/drcsim/2.2/VRC_Plugin_DRC_Vehicle) for making the vehicle move via topics doesn't work in a current build from source anymore. It worked before with drcsim-2.2 installed from .debs. Any pointers why that is and how to get back control of the vehice would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2137/vehicle-doesn%27t-react-to-drive-commands-in-current-default-branch-of-gazebo/drcsim-built-from-source/) by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/9/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 473 on 2013-03-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The handbrake functionality has been changed recently, so that it can be controlled manually. This caused a change in the behaviour when using ROS topic control, however, so that the handbrake cannot be directly commanded from 0 to 1, or 1 to 0. Try sending a command of 0.5 and then the final command and let me know if that works.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1